Regarding Derivation of Einstein Field Equations
In most sources I come across that try to justify the Einstein Field Equations outside the context of Einstein-Hilbert action, the argument goes mostly as follows: In analogy with the Poisson equation for Newtonian potential, it is tempting to postulate $R_{ab} = 8 \pi G_N T_{ab}$. However by virtue of the stress energy tensor being a conserved Noether current, $\nabla_a T^{ab} = 0$, but $\nabla_a R^{ab}$ is not generically zero. So we instead write $R_{ab} - \frac{1}{2} g_{ab} R = 8 \pi G_N T_{ab}$.
I am having trouble understanding this. Since we are only postulating, what exactly is the problem with restricting spacetime to only geometries that satisfy $\nabla_a R^{ab} = 0$? Would such a restriction be too strong? If so why? What is the geometric meaning of $\nabla_a R^{ab} = 0$? And why would be clearly unphysical to postulate that $\nabla_a R^{ab} = 0$ for any spacetime?

Wouldn't $\nabla_aR^{ab}=0$ require that there is no curvature (i.e., $R=0$) or that there is no matter?

If you focused only on vacuum spacetimes, then you can write the Einstein equations equivalently as $G_{ab}=0$ or $R_{ab}=0$. So the difference in the equations only manifests when you consider matter. Now, divergence-free Ricci curvature is equivalent to $dR=0$, where $R$ is the scalar curvature. So on a connected manifold, this would be equivalent to having constant scalar curvature. However, this already prohibits the cosmological FRW spacetimes with simple matter models, because there the scalar curvature can be explicitly computed, and barring exceptional cases, it’s usually non-constant.
